# Elixir assert_raise doesn't catch exceptions

Tags: elixir, ex-unit

I wrote this test case:

```
assert_raise ArgumentError, myFn(a,b)
```

but it does not evaluate in the way I'd expect. `myFn` raises an ArgumentError (`do: raise ArgumentError`), but it is not caught by `assert_raise`.

The example in the docs works just fine:

```
assert_raise ArithmeticError, fn ->
  1 + "test"
end
```

From the documentation:

> `assert_raise(exception, function)`
>   Asserts the `exception` is raised during `function` execution. Returns the rescued exception, fails otherwise

I'm guessing that in my test case, the arguments are evaluated first. But how should I've written it?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Wrapping the function call in a function is the way to go.

```
assert_raise ArgumentError, fn ->
  myFn(a, b)
end
```

I expected `assert_raise` to take a function call, but it takes a function.

Comment: Yes, `assert_rise` is not a macro, but normal function: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/f4a378f158b00aae0f2ee1c211eccc4314ecec01/lib/ex_unit/lib/ex_unit/assertions.ex#L498 This means that if you just pass `myFn(a, b)` it will be evaluated and the value will be passed to `assert_rise` which is already too late :)